# Accessing website with mechanicalsoup and failing to get table values

Tags: python, html, mechanicalsoup

I have some code to login to a website, go to the page I need, then grab the html which should contain a table. However, I'm missing the table's actual values. Clearly doing something wrong, I've never used mechanicalsoup before. D=

I'm using jupyter notebook, python 3.9. Here's my code:

```
import mechanicalsoup

# Accessing login page
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("https://myfakewebsite/")
browser.select_form('form[action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"]')

# Logging in
browser["Email"] = "me@fake.email"
browser["Password"] = "qwerty123"
browser.submit_selected()

# Moving to page I need after logging in
browser.open("https://myfakewebsite/more")

# Looking at what I've got
browser.page
```

In a regular browser, this is what I see if I right click and inspect the page:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lap3E.png)

From my code, this is what I see:

```
<table>
<tr><th align="left" valign="top">Education Facilitator</th><td data-bind="text: PEFContact()" valign="top"></td></tr>
</table>
```

In other words, the "PEFContact"'s actual email address is not there.

I've tried using browser.page.find_all(), but I still don't get the values. Warning: noob.

Comment: Since you've masked the web site you're trying to scrape it's impossible to be sure, but it's likely that the data is fetched by an AJAX call after the page has loaded.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks, I'll look it up. Chose to mask site as my employer likely doesn't want me scraping their website... though if they built it properly, I wouldn't have to.

Comment: If this is your employer's site why don't you just ask the people who maintain it for the data you need? They can probably just export it from the database.